# Can't remove file previously created by the application in Qt 4.8 on Win 7

Tags: windows, permissions, qt4, file-permissions

I've copied a .bat-file from Qt-ressources to a file system and executed it.
After that I wanted to delete the file, but it fails in Qt. If fails also when I restart the application. However, the file can be removed in the file-explorer.

I tried `QFile::remove` as well as `QDir::remove`. Static as well as not-static versions - no effect. 
I tried to call using native file-separator - didn't help either.

What is wrong with this code?

```
if ( QFileInfo( dataRootPath+"/backupdb.bat" ).exists() )
{
    //debugger stepps in
    QFile f( QFileInfo( dataRootPath+"/backupdb.bat" ).canonicalFilePath());
    f.remove(  );
}
```

Comment: I would guess this is most probably a permissions problem. Can you delete the file from the explorer?

Comment: What does the failure say?

Comment: @CristiFati What do you mean? QFile::remove returns bool. The result is "false"

Comment: @Murphy Yes: "However, the file can be removed in the file-explorer." Why permission-problem? The file is created and deleted from the same user. Could applications in Win 7 have different permissions? In this case Explorer more permissions than VisualStudio?

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't more explicit. I only worked with Qt a little bit years ago so my knowledge is a bit rusty. Isn't there a mechanism that lets the user know what was the error (that came from OS) for the failed operation?

Comment: Sure: `QFile::error()` and `errorString()`. The online references are your friend. Checking the permissions was just a first guess derived from your description; perhaps your application is running in some other user context.

Comment: On second thought, you should try to `close()` the file before you call `remove()`. Background: As a `QFile` object is flushed and closed on destruction if you don't do it explicitely, your code may try to delete a still non-existing file, and it's created nevertheless when the object goes out of scope.

Comment: And? Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem copying file from resources to file system and trying to remove it after that. QFile::errorString() returns "Access denied". So it seems that resource file has some nasty permissions that are copied by QFile::copy. May be it's possible to change permissions but I used my own 2 functions to copy file:

```
bool copyTextFile(QString srcPath, QString dstPath)
{
    QFile file(srcPath);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return false;
    return writeTextFile(QString::fromUtf8(file.readAll()), dstPath);
}

bool writeTextFile(QString data, QString dstPath)
{
    QFile file(dstPath);
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return false;
    QTextStream stream(&file);
    stream << data;
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I change its permissions before remove it.

```
QFile::copy(":/res/1.txt", "D:\\1.txt");
QFile file("D:\\1.txt");
file.setPermissions(file.permissions() |
                    QFileDevice::WriteOwner |
                    QFileDevice::WriteUser |
                    QFileDevice::WriteGroup |
                    QFileDevice::WriteOther);
file.remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error, but in my case the posted solutions did not work. However, it turned out that I had created a `std::ofstream` object in my code, that was unclosed. Thus, this was keeping the source file open which prevented the copying on Windows.